# How to use ReportingCloud in asp.net web site?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, report

Recently I have started to work with SSRS and found [ReportingCloud](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportingcloud/?source=navbar).  It says

```
ReportingCloud provides an open source quality implementation 
as an extension of the RDL specification
```

I haven't found any tutorial/documentation on how to use it in sourceforge or via google search.

Can anyone give an walk-through/example on **How to use ReportingCloud?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one partial example available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/reportingcloud/forums/forum/1116661/topic/4571059.

The example takes an existing RDL file, parses and executes it and then places the HTML output into an asp.net Literal Control for display in the browser.

That code snippet is repeated here:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("C:\MyFolder\MyReport.rdl");

RDLParser rdlp = new RDLParser(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
rdlp.Parse();

MemoryStreamGen ms = new MemoryStreamGen();
ProcessReport pr = new ProcessReport(rdlp.Report, ms);
pr.Run(null, OutputPresentationType.ASPHTML);

// Dump memory stream (HTML Text) to an out-of-box ASPX Literal control
this.LiteralReportHtml.Text = ms.GetText();
```

To do this you'll need a reference to `ReportingCloud.Engine`.

---

I'm not sure exactly what your bigger goals are but I'd like to draw your attention to another open source project on GitHub called `My-FyiReporting` https://github.com/majorsilence/My-FyiReporting

Just like `ReportingCloud`, `My-FyiReporting` is a fork of `FyiReporting` (which has gone dormant).

The big difference as far as you are concerned is that `My-FyiReporting` **has ASP.NET samples and an ASP.NET user control** [link](https://github.com/majorsilence/My-FyiReporting/wiki/ASP.NET-Report-Control).  This might be the fast way to get to what you need.

File `ORIGINALPROJECT.TXT` from `ReportingCloud` says:

> The ReportingCloud is a fork from the original project fyiReporting
>   4.1 (http://www.fyireporting.com).

File `readme.md` from `My-FyiReporting` says:

> My-FyiReporting is a fork of fyiReporting. I cannot stress this
>   enough. This is a FORK. The main purpose is to make sure that I have a
>   copy of fyiReporting since that project seems to be dead.